# Databricks IO Cache with sc.parallelize()?

Tags: databricks

I went through https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/databricks-io-cache.html but there is not a single line of code of example on how to use the DBIO cache(instead of the standard Spark RDD cache) in code, apart from setting a configuration setting to enable DBIO cache.

Am I to assume that if I enable that setting `spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", "true")` then in my spark job whatever RDD I create will be basically treated as a DBIO cache?? What if I want to distinguish and have both in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBIO Caching works with Parquet datasets only at this time. So as long as you're loading a DataFrame from Parquet then you will get use of the cache. You can confirm by looking at the `Storage` tab in the Spark UI which will show how much you've cached so far. Also, to make it easier just use i3 instance types so that the DBIO cache is enabled by default.

Comment: No, because it doesn't actually change the Spark plan, it's completely transparent. However, in the task locality level you'll see it as being NODE_LOCAL when DBIO cache is being used vs PROCESS_LOCAL when it's not.